# How to sort a multidimensional array based on the first element(float value) of each array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array which contains a bunch of array elements, with each array element containing two elements each. This is the array:

```
Array
(
    Array(0.577677, '/art and entertainment/visual art and design/painting'),
    Array(0.576528, '/technology and computing/internet technology/email'),
    Array(0.197858, '/business and industrial/energy/oil/oil and gas prices'),
    Array(0.707193, '/sports/wrestling'),
    Array(0.506016, '/style and fashion/beauty/cosmetics'),
    Array(0.144159, '/food and drink/beverages/alcoholic beverages/cocktails and beer')
)
```

Now, I want to sort this array on the basis of the first element of each array element.

For example in the above array the first element in the sorted array should be `Array(0.707193 [1], '/sports/wrestling')` and the last element should be `Array (0.144159, '/food and drink/beverages/alcoholic beverages/cocktails and beer')`

How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: Take a look at the examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php, you may find them helpful.

Comment: arsort? [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't subtract the number from each other to order your array, since you have float numbers in your array. And the function in your sorting function must return a integer number bigger, equal or less than 0.

Also as noted in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> **Caution:**
>   Returning **non-integer** values from the comparison function, such as float, will result in an **internal cast to integer** of the callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

So just use `<`/`>` and `==` to comapre your numbers and sort the array:

```
uasort($arr,function($a,$b){
    if($a['0'] ==  $b['0'])
        return 0;
    return $a['0'] >  $b['0'] ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uasort($memberArray,function($a,$b){
            return $a['0'] -  $b['0'];
        });
```

Comment: You can directly `return $a['0'] -  $b['0']` ^^

Comment: Above solution returns the following array:  `Array ( [4] => Array ( [0] => 0.506016 [1] => /style and fashion/beauty/cosmetics ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 0.144159 [1] => /food and drink/beverages/alcoholic beverages/cocktails and beer ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 0.707193 [1] => /sports/wrestling ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 0.197858 [1] => /business and industrial/energy/oil/oil and gas prices ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 0.576528 [1] => /technology and computing/internet technology/email ) [0] => Array ( [0] => 0.577677 [1] => /art and entertainment/visual art and design/painting ) )` Doesn't seem to work